# How can I implement Matlab imshow(image,[]) in java opencv?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, matlab, opencv

i am trying to implement the MR8 filter for texture feature extraction, i have done coding as per the Matlab code on http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/texclass/filters.html. now i want to display the 38 filtered image after convolution. In matlab the image is displayed as imshow(F(:,:,1),[]).

How can I do the same with java opencv?

Comment: can you clarify, if you're talking about opencv's java wrappers, or javacv ?

Comment: to be more specific i want the display the image in javacv as in matlab imshow(I,[low high]), how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to show images in Open Java (in a `JFrame`):

```
public static void ShowImage(Mat img, String title, Integer...locs) {
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();

    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;

    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle(title);

        if ((locs != null) && (locs.length > 0)) {
            frame.setLocation(locs[0], locs[1]);
        } else {
            frame.setLocation(START_X_LOC, START_Y_LOC);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can call it with only the image Mat:

```
ShowImage(imgMat, null, null);
```

Or, you can add title or the location:

```
int[] loc = {100,200};
ShowImage(imgMat, "Image", loc);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a readymade solution for Imshow() equivalent in Java OpenCV Its simple to use . API will look like:

```
Imshow im = new Imshow("Title");
im.showImage(matimage);
```

Visit here https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV